# Toggling a non-attr_accessible variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, toggle, attr-accessible

I am creating a Rails application that is a blogging platform, with many contributing writers.  My **User** model has a **:writer** boolean attribute to indicate whether or not a particular user has permission to publish an article.  In order to prevent mass assignment, the **:writer** attribute is **NOT** listed under **attr_accessible** for the **User** model.  Instead, I thought of creating a function similar to the following, to allow for toggling of the writer-permissions:

```
def toggle_writer    
  if User.find(:id).writer?
    User.find(:id).update_attribute(:writer, false)
  else
    User.find(:id).update_attribute(:writer, true)
  end
  flash[:success] = "User permissions toggled."
  redirect_to admintools_users_path
end
```

I have several questions regarding this approach, though:

1. How would I invoke this from a view?  Is there a way to invoke a function via a **link_to** or **button_for**?
2. Where would I put such a function?  In a controller, or helper?
3. Would I need to edit any routes in the **config/routes.rb** file?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can.
2. Better if you put it in the `users_controller`.
3. Yes, you would. As this action is going to update a single user, so, you should do the following in `routes.rb`:

   ```
    resources :users do
      member do #this means you are doing with a certain object
        get :toggle_writer, :as => :toggle_writer_for # this line will generate toggle_writer_for_user_path route
      end
    end
   ```

Now you can use this route with `link_to`, like `link_to("Toggle writer", toggle_writer_for_user_path(@user))`, where `@user` is you can get from `params[:id]`.

Comment: Thanks, Kishie!  This worked perfectly.  Where can I learn about route constructions like this?

Comment: I used put, with link_to ... :method => :put since this action is updating the database